# Pass more parameters to an API Postrequest web api

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

This is mine api it expects two parameters !

```
public void CreateRejectionChild([FromBody] IEnumerable<QMSRejectionChild> ChildData, string MasterId)
        {


         }
```

I am doing post request like this

```
string urlx = "http://192.168.100.28:8085/api/QMSRejection/CreateRejectionChild";
                    var clientx = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(urlx);
                    StringContent contentx = new StringContent((JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChildData)+MasterID), 
                        Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage responsex = await clientx.PostAsync(urlx, contentx);
```

I am not sure Am I passing correctly the 2nd Object or not ? Because it gives me a 404 error as a response !

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+rest+api+post+multiple+parameters+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: solved issue using this post by passing Id in Url !

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You could posrt as answer and accpet it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Api to

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Rej/MasterId/{MasterId}")]
public string CreateRejectionChild([FromBody] IEnumerable<QMSRejectionChild> ChildData,[FromUri] string MasterId)
        {
         
        }
```

I passed 2nd parameter as url and that worked for me !